# Surface integral of vector over square plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, surface-integrals

> Problem 2.25 D.K.Cheng
> [image]

The unit normal vector for the plane is found as the cross product of the two vectors spanning the plane.
$$\mathbf{a_n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\bigg(\mathbf{a_y}+\mathbf{a_z}\bigg) $$
The dot product of the vector field and the plane's normal vector is
$$\mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{a_n}=\frac{5}{\sqrt{2}} $$
The last thing to do is evaluate the integral $\displaystyle\int^d_c\int^b_a \frac{5}{\sqrt{2}} \text{d}s\:$ however, I'm uncertain what the limits of the integrals should be.

The plane doesn't lie in either the xy/yz/xz-plane, so I can't just set x/y/z = $0$, set the limits to $a=c=0$, $b=d=2$ and then integrate.

How do I determine what the limits should be? The answer to the problem is supposedly $\displaystyle\int_S \mathbf{F} \cdot \text{d}\mathbf{s} = 20$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The surface is in the plane $y + z = 2$ with normal vector $(0, 1, 1)$.

Also $S$ is not a square surface but a rectangular surface though its projection $E$ in xy-plane is a square with bounds $~0 \leq x \leq 2, 0 \leq y \leq 2$

As you have normalized the normal vector, note that $dS = \sqrt 2 ~ dA$ where $dA$ is the area element of the projection in xy-plane.

So the integral is,

$$\displaystyle \iint_S \frac{5}{\sqrt2} ~ dS = \iint_E 5 ~ dA = 20.$$

Comment: How do you see that $dS=\sqrt{2}$? To me that is not obvious at all.

Comment: @carl in fact if you took the normal vector $(0, 1, 1)$ without normalizing, you would straightaway get $\iint 5 ~ dA$. Now $dS = \sqrt 2 ~ dA$ because magnitude of normal vector $(0, 1, 1)$ is $\sqrt2$. Do you know how to find surface area of a disk?

Comment: Yeah it’s $\pi r^2$. But the vector (0,2,2) is also a normal vector for the plane, right? And the magnitude of that is $\sqrt{8}$. It’s still not clear to me where that $dS = \sqrt{2} dA$ comes from.

Comment: They are all normal vectors to the same plane but if you are projecting a surface $z = f(x, y)$ in xy-plane, you need to map $dS$ to $dA$ using normal vector with z-component as $1$, in other words, $z = 2 - y$ and not $2z = 4 - 2y$

Comment: That is why we define the surface as $z = f(x, y)$ and then the surface area formula is $\displaystyle dS = \sqrt{1 + \left(\frac{dz}{dx}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{dz}{dy}\right)^2} ~ dA$? That $1$ in the square root is because $\frac{d(z)}{dz} = 1$

Comment: Ahh okay, and $\frac{dz}{dx}=0$, and $\frac{dz}{dy}=1$ hence $dS = \sqrt{2}$. Is that formula for $dS$ only valid for planes? And one last thing, if we have a plane $z=2-2y$ then we would have the relation $dS = \sqrt{5} dA$ right?

Comment: Yes that would be $dS = \sqrt{5} ~ dA$. No this formula for surface area works for all regular surfaces that can be defined as $z = f(x, y)$. Of course you could change that depending on which coordinate plane you are projecting the surface in. Sometimes it might be easier to project it in yz-plane for example. Then you have $x = f(y, z)$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience, Math Lover. You have really helped me today.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133040/discussion-between-math-lover-and-carl).